# What's the difference between $request->file->store($path) and $request->file->move($path, $filename)?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to upload multiple files in the system, but I couldn't figure out differences between many available storage functions.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear. From docs:
Laravel makes it very easy to store uploaded files using the store method on an uploaded file instance. Simply call the store method with the path at which you wish to store the uploaded file.
The move method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_store` - By default, the store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. The path to the file will be returned by the store method so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your database. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)

`file_move` - Move a file to a new location (native php `rename` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php))